Snakemake: No storage provider found
While running snakemake -call results/test-elec/networks/elec_s_6_ec_lcopt_Co2L-24H.nc --configfile config/test/config.electricity.yaml in the command line, I got this error message:

WorkflowError in file /Users//Documents/Code/3E/pypsa-eur/rules/retrieve.smk, line 67:
No storage provider found for query https://zenodo.org/record/6382570/files/{cutout}.nc. Either install the required storage plugin or check your query. Also consider to explicitly specify the storage provider to get a more informative error message.

When I browse to the given page, I get a 301 error:

The web page at https://zenodo.org/record/6382570/files/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

Is this error the reason or did I miss something? Any help would be appreciated!

I had the same issue, and I managed to resolve it by
pip3 install snakemake-storage-plugin-http

The issue is that the "storage(...)" directive in the yaml file wants to use an HTTP "input" but the plugin is not installed. The documentation should be updated on that.
I have not downloaded yet the "cutouts" part, but it seems to be there: (the latest version) https://zenodo.org/records/6382570
I hope this solves your issue.

The HTTP storage plugin is included in the environment.yaml
https://github.com/PyPSA/pypsa-eur/blob/c50a3770ea20b65cfd76956e0c86492ebbcf4d3a/envs/environment.yaml#L63
